# Writing Tests for a CLI that Creates Files and Directories

Tags: unit-testing, file, testing

I am designing a Command Line Interface program, but I am unsure of how to test it

The program is fairly straightforward:

```
>>> my_cmd <name_of_file> <file_contents>
```

The program will generate a file with the given name and write file_contents to it

This problem isn't specific to just one language; I would like to know what the best practice is for this problem

Should I actually create the file, test if it exists, and then delete it?

Or should I just test if the path already exists without creating the file?

Answer (score 0):

I would argue that yes, you need tests that check all the scenarios that are important for the application, including those that create and work on files. That's the way you get confidence about the system working and have safety to modify it (because tests will fail if you break something).

Comment: So you believe I should actually create the file when running the tests?

Comment: There do need to be some tests that actually hit the filesystem, yes